# SharePoint 2013 Wiki Site template missing

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to create a new Wiki Site in SharePoint 2013 and I'm following the guide here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-wiki-HA010226177.aspx#BM2

So I go to Site Settings -> Sites and Workspaces -> Create. On this page you specify the title, url, etc for your new site. In the Template Selection section there is supposed to be a Wiki Site template under the Collaboration tab according to the above guide. However, the only templates I see are Team Site, Blog, Project Site and Community Site. There is also an Enterprise tab with some more templates underneath it, but no Wiki Site.

How can I create a Wiki Site in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Apparently there is a "Page layouts and site templates" link under "Look and Feel" where one can enable site templates for a site. However I cannot see this link. Do I need specific permissions to see this link?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Site settings > Page layout and site template settings > Subsite templates
2. Check the box marked "Subsites can only use the following site templates"
3. Add the templates and try to create your wiki site again